# Domain is not allowed, og:url/type/title not set... (using comments plugin)

Tags: plugins, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-comments

We're testing the FB comments plugin on our articles, only I continue to get 'url not reachable' warnings.

So I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here - it's telling me og:url, og:type, and og:title aren't set, but not only does it show them as set below, it's also recognizing the url as being of type 'article' when telling me it can't access the domain - and the domain is very clearly set in the app properties.

As long as I'm here asking, is it possible to okay an application for more than one domain?  We have a staging site with a different domain and it would be convenient to be able to do things solely on it.

I've searched and not found this precise problem, but please excuse me if I'm doing something completely stupid and obvious here.

[image: Screenshot shows properties set and yet not set]

[image: Screenshot shows app is set to root domain]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must write `www.sitename.com` in the fb application